# OnBackPressed() for different activities in same function

Tags: onbackpressed

I want to navigate on previous activity by using `onBackPressed()`. I tried the following code :

```
Intent i=new Intent(detail.this,Data.class);
startActivity(i);
```

It's working, navigating on the `Data.java` file by manually. But my problem is that instead of `Data.class` there are other activities according to my need, like

```
Homepage.class==>Data.class====>detail.class
Homepage.class==>Inbox.class====>detail.class
Homepage.class==>Information.class====>detail.class
```

means like this,

For 1st condition

```
Intent i = new Intent(detail.this, Data.class);
startActivity(i);
```

For 2nd condition

```
Intent i = new Intent(detail.this, Inbox.class);
startActivity(i);
```

For 3rd condition

```
Intent i = new Intent(detail.this, Information.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Now my question is: how to know the previous activity class name and how to replace the class name data.class in following line automatically

```
Intent i = new Intent(detail.this, Data.class);
```

Comment: 1. why do you need the previous class name ?. 2 how do you decide manually to start Inbox.class or Information.class ?

Comment: There are three activities : A,B,C  suppose i navigate from

Comment: There are FIVE activities : A,B,C,D,E  suppose i navigate from  A-->B-->C  and  D-->B-->C  and   E-->B-->C ,when i press the back button in C it goes to B correctly, but when back button press in B activity there is confusion that which is the prev activity.My prblem is that how to detect the previous activity  in such condition.

Comment: I am still missing the point on why would you try to find previous activity because if you start activity B from A or D or E, the system knows from which activity was B started and it goes back to the right activity when onBackPressed is triggered. However here is one way to find out the starting activity: you can put a parameter in the starting intent with the starting activity(intent.putExtra("activity","A")) as a string and use startActivityForResult if you want to get back some result from B to A or D or E

Comment: My misunderstanding........now working properly......!...Thank you.